# How to add bold text in Tooltips in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, gwt, tooltip, html

I'm using a native javascript method in my gwt project und try to add tooltips in the RTA http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html . That works fine by using:

```
private native void addHtmlSpanHighlight(Element elem, String type, 
String objectId, String tooltip)/*-{ 
var range = elem.contentWindow.getSelection().getRangeAt(0), content = range 
.extractContents(), span = document.createElement('SPAN'); 

span.setAttribute("type", type); 
span.setAttribute("value", objectId); 
span.setAttribute("style", "background-color:#ffd700"); 
span.setAttribute("title", tooltip) 
span.appendChild(content); 

var htmlContent = span.innerHTML; 
range.insertNode(span); 
elem.blur(); 
}-*/;
```

So the span has the tooltip. But here is my question:

Is there any smart and easy possibility to set bold tags in the String of the tooltip (example : title="This is a **Test**) without using css or javascript frameworks?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style tooltips.

You can create a different element that will act as a tooltip, and style it. One possible technique is described here:

http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

Answer (score 0):

Try using DecoratedPopupPanel then add mouse hover handler for your panel, see example in this [link](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwBasicPopup)